# generate and show password

Tags: javascript, html, passwords

i have a form with a html table.
my table is :

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="password[]"/>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="radio" value="1" onchange="generatePassword()"/>Short<br />
    <input type="radio" value="2" onchange="generatePassword()"/>Medium<br />
    <input type="radio" value="3" onchange="generatePassword()" />Long
</td>
<tr>
</table>
```

In my code, there is a button at the bottom and when it is clicked, it clones the table row. So, i dont know number of rows or number of password fields in my table. Because of clonning the row, i could not give id to my password field. So, I couldnt decide how to reach a text box without id. But i need to show my generated password in password field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do. You can find an input field from `generatePassword` like this:

```
function generatePassword(inp) {
    var textbox = inp.parentNode.parentNode.cells[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    textbox.value = 'password ' + inp.value;
}
```

You would also change markup a little. Add `name` attribute to radio buttons and reference current input with `this`:

```
<input type="radio" name="generate" onchange="generatePassword(this)" value="1" />
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BHb3N/

Answer (score 1):

Use `.getElementsByName` instead of id:

```
document.getElementsByName('password[]')[0].value="anyvalue";
```

### [Fiddle1](http://jsfiddle.net/Vt4rN/)

## ***OR***

Use `.getElementsByTagName`

```
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value="anyvalue";
```

### [Fiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/Vt4rN/1/)

---

### **[New fiddle in response to comment](http://jsfiddle.net/Vt4rN/2/)**

Comment: i also dont know the index of row. Your answer is for first row. But what happened when user click the radio button in 5th row?

Answer (score 1):

You could use Classes instead of an ID.

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="myPassword" value="test" name="password[]" />
<input type="text" class="myPassword" value="test" name="password[]" />
<input type="text" class="myPassword" value="test" name="password[]" />
```

JS

```
var passwords = document.getElementsByClassName('myPassword') || document.querySelectorAll('myPassword'); //querySelectorAll for IE <= 8

 for (var i = 0; i < passwords.length; i++) {
    console.log(passwords[i].value);
 }
```